# Grabbing a portion of a string like substr

Tags: c++

So I'm making a function that is similar to SubStr. This is an assignment so I cannot use the actual function to do this. So far I have created a function to take a string and then get the desired substring. My problem is returning the substring. In the function when I do `Substring[b] = AString[b];` the substring is empty, but if I `cout` from inside the function I get the desired substring. So what is wrong with my code?

Here is a working demo: http://ideone.com/4f5IpA

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void subsec(char AString[], char Substring[], int start, int length);

int main() {
    char someString[] = "abcdefg";
    char someSubString[] = "";

    subsec(someString, someSubString, 1, 3);
    cout << someSubString << endl;

    return 0;
}

void subsec(char AString[], char Substring[], int start, int length) {
    for (int b = start; b <= length; b++) {
        Substring[b] = AString[b];
    }
}
```

Comment: for your assignment, do you have to use `char array`, or can you use `std::string`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this does what you're looking for?  It's hard to say as your initial implementation used the length parameter as more of an end position.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void subsec(char AString[], char Substring[], int start, int length)
{
    const int end = start + length;
    int pos = 0;
    for(int b = start; b < end; ++b)
    {
        Substring[pos++] = AString[b];
    }
    Substring[pos] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    char someString[50] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char someSubString[50];

    subsec(someString, someSubString, 13, 10);
    cout << someSubString << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code:

1) The char array`someSubString` has size 1 which cannot hold the substring.

2) The `subsec` is not correctly implemented, you should copy to the `Substring` from index 0.
Also remember to add `\0` at the end of the substring.

```
void subsec(char AString[], char *Substring, int start, int length) {
     int ii = 0;
     for (int jj = start; jj <= length; jj++, ii++) {
         Substring[ii] = AString[jj];
     }

     Substring[ii] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate more than 1 byte for someSubString i.e.

```
char someSubString[] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

or just

```
char someSubString[100];
```

if you know the max size you'll ever need.

Either would allocate enough space for the string you're copying to it. Then, you're not doing anything about the terminating 0 either. At the end of a C-style string there needs to be a terminating null to signify end of string. Otherwise cout will print something like;

```
abcdefgxxxxxxx
```

if you initialized with x's as I indicated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code as it stands. Firstly, as your compiler is no doubt warning you, in C++ a string literal has type `const char[]`, not just `char[]`.

Secondly, you need to have enough space to store your substring. A good way to do this is for your function to allocate the space it needs, and then pass back a pointer to this memory. This is the way things are typically done in C code. The only thing is that you have to remember to delete the allocated array when you're done with it. (There are other, better ways to do this in C++, with things like smart pointers and wrapper objects, but those come later :-) ).

Thirdly, you'll have a problem if you request a `length` which is actually longer than the passed-in string -- you'll run off the end and start copying random memory (or just crash), which is definitely not what you want. C strings are terminated with a "nul byte" -- so you need to check whether you've come across this.

Speaking of the nul, you need to make sure that your substring ends with one.

Lastly, it's not really a problem but there's no need for the `start` parameter, you can just pass a pointer to the middle of the array if you want to.

```
char* substring(const char* str, int length)
{
    // Allocate memory for substring;
    char* subs = new char[length+1];

    // Copy characters from given string
    int i = 0;
    while (i < length && str[i] != '\0') {
        subs[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }

    // Append the nul byte
    subs[i] = '\0';

    return subs;
}

int main()
{
    const char someString[] = "foobarbaz"; // Note -- must be const in C++

    char* subs = substring(someString + 3, 3);

    assert(strcmp(subs, "bar") == 0);

    delete subs;
}
```